# How can I iterate through nested classes and pass the object to my function

Tags: c#, class

I've the following class, which has two nested classes;

```
public class Request
{
    public Hotel Hotel {get;set;}
    public Room Room {get;set;}
}
```

The nested classes

```
public class Hotel
{
    public int HotelId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public string CountryCode {get;set;}
}
```

and

```
public class Room
{
   public int RoomId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Basically I can create my object fine;

```
Request oRequest = new Request();
```

What I want to do is be able to iterate through the class finding any nested classes and pass these to a function like

```
Type t = oBookingRequest.GetType();

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties())
{
   CallMyFunction(pi);
}
```

The problem I'm having is when calling CallMyFunction(pi) I can't actually view the class property values as if I'm not passing the pi as the actual object ?  Am I doing this correctly, because if I call the function CallMyFunction(oRequest.Hotel) it works fine.

EDIT:

The function CallMyFunction is a ValidationContext function using ValidationResult, so I need to pass the actual object containing all the properties, and not each individual property value.  The function CallMyFunction is

```
    private List<ValidationResult> CallMyFunction (object oObject)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(oObject, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(oObject, context, results, false);

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't get the class data? Do you mean the property values? You also write `nested classes` yet you only show two properties. Are the classes really define inside the Request class?

Comment: Yes sorry I mean property values

Comment: Shows us the definition of `CallMyFunction`.

Comment: Don't use reflection for everything. Why don't you simply use the property you need, e.g. `oBookingRequest.Hotel.Name`?

Comment: The problem I have is I don't know the property names, so I'm wanting to write a loop to go through the class, getting any nested classes and pass these objects to my function.

Comment: I've updated my question for more clarification of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the actual value of the property into your function using [PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx):

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties())
{
  CallMyFunction(pi.GetValue(oBookingRequest, null));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help my problem.  I've updated my question to add more clarification.